# Proves that $F(a^2) \subseteq F(a)$ and $F(a + b) \subseteq F(a,b)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

This question originates from Pinter's Abstract Algebra, Chapter 27, Exercise E2.

> Recall the definition of $F(a)$. It is a field such that
>   (i) $F \subseteq F(a)$;
>   (ii)$a \in F(a)$; 
>   (iii) any field containing $F$ and $a$ contains $F(a)$.
>
> Proves that $F(a^2) \subseteq F(a)$ and $F(a + b) \subseteq F(a,b)$. 
>   [$F(a, b)$ is the field containing $F, a$, and $b$, and contained in any other field containing $F, a$ and $b$.] Why are the reverse inclusions not necessarily true?

$a \in F(a)\implies a^2\in F(a)$ by closure of ring multiplication
$\implies F(a^2)\subseteq F(a)$ by (iii).  However,
$a$ is not necessarily a member of $F(a^2)$.  For example, $\sqrt{2}$ is not a member of $\Bbb{Q}(2)$. Hence, $F(a)\subseteq F(a^2)$ does not hold.

$a+b \in F(a,b)$ by closure of group addition $\implies F(a+b)\subseteq F(a,b)$ by (iii).
$ab\in F(a, b)$ by closure of ring multiplication.  However, $ab$ is not necessarily a member of $F(a+b)$.  For example, $\sqrt{2}$ is not a member of $\Bbb{Q}(1+\sqrt{2})$.  Hence, $F(a,b)\subseteq F(a+b)$ does not hold.

Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean "$a, b$" (as in "$a$ and $b$") instead of "$ab$" a few places, but otherwise it's all correct.

However, your "is not necessarily a member" claims are completely without proofs. In this case the best proof would be an example.

Add a concrete example for each "is not necessarily a member" claim, and this is perfect. For instance, $\sqrt 2$ is well-known to not be a member of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2^2)=\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Added concrete examples.